# Bootstrap 5: Elements Displaying Together at 767px Screen Width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap 5 for a website and there's a problem displaying elements when the screen width is 767px.

For example I have 2 different element for showing product info for mobile and screen - .best-selling-product-mobile and .best-selling-product-screen show together

Html code

```
<div class="product-card-details best-selling-product-screen">
    <div class="product-card-prices">
        //price here            
    </div>
    <div class="product-card-add-to-cart">
        //add to cart btn here 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product-card-details best-selling-product-mobile">
    <div class="product-card-prices">
        //price here            
    </div>
    <div class="product-card-add-to-cart">
        //add to cart btn here 
    </div>
</div>
```

And css

```
.product-card-details {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
    min-height: 50px;
}

.product-card-prices {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    text-align: end;
}

.product-card-add-to-cart {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}


@media ( min-width: 768px){
  .best-selling-product-mobile{
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media ( max-width: 767px){
    .best-selling-product-screen{
        display: none !important;
    }
}

body {
    transition: margin-left 0.2s;
}

*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: var(--bs-body-line-height);
    text-align: var(--bs-body-text-align);
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

And similar problems I get for another element. Also tis is only when screen width =767px. It ok if width =768px or 768px.

It seems that with a width of 767 pixels, both styles for width<767px and for width>768px work

Comment: By looking to css it seem that you were taking flex property wrongly so could you provide image or anything that you want to create so it would be easy to understand.